# Display a data structure with a nested array in the handsontable

Tags: handsontable

The data structure of the objects I want to display in a handsontable looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "job": "farmer, 
    "persons":
        [
        {"name": "mike"}, {"name":"nina"}
        ]
    },
    {
    "job": "carpenter, 
    "persons":
        [
        {"name": "lenny"}
        ]
    }
]
```

The table I have in mind would look something like this:

```
job        |  name 
-----------------------
farmer     | mike
           | nina
carpenter  | lenny
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fLqre6w7/

As you can see I wrote:

```
columns: [
  {data: 'job'},
  {data: 'persons'}
]
```

I would love to write:

```
columns: [
  {data: 'job'},
  {data: 'persons.name'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With nestedRows you could get close to this. http://jsfiddle.net/qoez14w0/1/

```
var sourceDataObject = [
      {job: "Farmers", name: null, __children: [{name:"mike"}, {name:"nina"}]},
      {job: "Carpenters", __children: [{name:"lenny"}]}
    ],
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: sourceDataObject,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: ['Farmers', 'Name'],
    nestedRows: true,
    contextMenu: true,
  });
```